# ¿Cómo guardar un dataframe dentro de un for, donde el nombre contega el contador?

Tags: r

A través de RODBC hago una consulta SQL repetitiva según un período que es el contador dentro del for (valor i), ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el nombre del dataframe de salida incluya el valor de i?

Answer (score 0):

No es buena práctica crear dinámicamente objetos, para esto tenemos las listas. Puedes:

#### Usar una lista y asignar los resultados por índice

```
data <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
    # Esto hace las veces de la asignación de cada resulset 
    data[[i]] <- runif(5)recibido
}
```

Luego el acceso a cada elemento es con los dobles corchetes y el índice:

```
data[[2]]
```

#### Usar una lista pero nombrar cada elemento

```
data <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
    # Esto hace las veces de la asignación de cada resulset 
    data[[paste0("datos_",i)]] <- runif(5)
}
```

Y ahora sí puedes acceder por nombre:

```
data$datos_2
```

De todas formas, lo que preguntas lo puedes hacer usando `assign()` de la siguiente forma:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    # Esto hace las veces de la asignación de cada resulset 
    assign(paste0("datos_",i), runif(5))
}
```

Y con esto hemos creado los 10 objetos de forma dinámica, simplemente accedemos por sus nombres:

```
datos_2
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! solucionado